# Debian 10 and Intel I350 - Interfaces disabled after boot

Tags: networking, debian, nic, intel, debian-buster

I have a server with an Intel i350 quad nic on the motherboard (SuperMicro X9DRi-LN4F+).

This server ran in production for many years no problems (Debian 9).

Recently, I moved the server to a new location, upgraded the hard drives. I installed Debian 10 in it, but ran into some issues:

Before the installer starts, the interface is on, have lights on the ports, etc. Once the installer starts and tries to bring up the interfaces/detects hardware, it names the 4 interfaces as follows:

- eno1
- rename2
- rename3
- rename4

Once the installer tries to assign addresses/etc, the network card seems to turn off (no lights) and Debian cannot bring up the interfaces.

I continued the install without network, booted into my new Debian install and the same behavior occurs.

I thought the issue could be with the interfaces, but I live-booted to Ubuntu and it works just fine. I installed a 10G card for connecting to a storage server and I was able to bring that interface and communicate with the other server no problem.

I read of a similar issue via a bug report:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928328

But all of my ports were already set to "on".

Is there a specific driver that Debian 10 does not come with for the i350 nic?

Update: I installed Ubuntu for now and it seems to work, still unsure why Debian did not want to work with the i350 nic.

Comment: Those names are definitely wrong. Switch to another vt and check `dmesg` while running the installer to see if you can find any error messages.

Comment: No issues that I can see in the dmesg output. I can see from the output that it sees the NIC and then renames all the interfaces.

Comment: Did you check it _while booted into the installer_?

Comment: Correct, I put in my install media and ran the installer, NIC is on until after you select langage, etc and it attempts to detect hardware. I swapped to another vt and went through dmesg, no errors that I can see, when trying to detect hardware I see the messages of it finding the NIC, etc and the last entry is just "rename3: renamed from eth1", etc

Comment: OK, that's bizarre if you really see nothing else. There should be something somewhere to indicate why renaming is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This also still occurs with Debian 11 installer. I have an X10 based board also with 4 I350 interfaces.

Devices, while they are named the enp1s0fX style, show link to the switch when booting up until the installer tries to 'detect' link, then the link lights go out and they are unusable.